# Angular2: Input Controls losses value inside form tag with ngFor

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have developed a page in Angular2 which uses form tag and I have rendered input controls using ngFor in table tag.

I have created model (DataModal) to represent each row of table. I have created list of model (DataModalList) and kept adding each model into it on click of button (addNewRow)

I am facing the problem of selected input values getting removed on adding new row.
**Things are working fine when I removed the form tag**
I need form tag to perform validations.

Please find below code:

Model:

```
import {DropDownModel} from '../models/dropDownModel'; 
export class DataModal {
  dropdown: DropDownModel[];
  selectedValue: string;
  constructor() {           
          this.selectedValue = "0";  
      }
 }
```

Component:

```
addNewRow() { 
    let dataModal = new DataModal();
    dataModal.dropdown = response; //values are coming from api
    this.DataModalList.push(dataModal);
}
```

Html:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitEditForm(form.valid)">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of DataModalList;let i= index ">
            <td class="col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <label class="control-label" for="BoxID"> Box Number </label>
                    <select class="form-control" #BoxID="ngModel"  name="BoxID" [(ngModel)]="item.selectedValue">
                             <option  value="0" disabled > -- select -- </option>
                             <option *ngFor="let element of item.dropdown"                                                           
                              [value]="element.value" >{{element.label}}</option>
                         </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <a title="Add" (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn blue btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></form>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use reactive form groups. Provide a working plunker with your code and I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controls need unique names to work properly in html page.

So use **index-i** also in **name** attribute.
use below code:

```
<select class="form-control" #BoxID="ngModel" name="BoxID-{{i}}"
[(ngModel)]="item.selectedValue" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}>
<option  value="0" disabled > -- select -- </option>
<option *ngFor="let element of item.dropdown"                                                           
    [value]="element.value" >{{element.label}}
</option>
</select>
```